# SQLite: update every 'null' string record in database

Tags: string, sqlite, null

I'm not sure if this was my mistake while I was importing CSV to my database or it was on CSV file itself but almost every record that should be null has now a 'null' string value in it.

The problematic columns have integer or float datatypes they are not string at all...

Is there a reasonably quick way to update the entire database and substitute each 'null' record with a real null?

If not the entire database, a single table would also work since I only got 3 tables. (but it would be nicer to learn anyways)

I'm trying to do something like:

SELECT ALL 'NULL' values in DATABASE and REPLACE with =NULL

***Question is for SQLite, I know there are solutions for SQL Server or other SQL types but couldn't find any for SQLite

Answer (score 0):

if your sqlite has version 3.8.5 or higher, You can replace **NULL** string with `NULL` as following

```sql
UPDATE
    table_name
SET
    column_name = REPLACE(column_name,'NULL','');
```

But the problem: you should do this for each column in each table of your database.

#### REFERENCES

- [sqlite-replace-function (www.sqlitetutorial.net)](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-replace-function/)
- [replace-update-all-rows-sqlite (dba.stackexchange.com)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/194790/replace-update-all-rows-sqlite)

#### Edit: Lengthy Approach

In this approach, we will get data out from sqlite file and use code editor to **find and replace**

Step 1

Take all data out from database and delete original data.

```sql
sqlite3> .mode insert
sqlite3> .output filename.sql
sqlite3> select * from table_name;
sqlite3> delete from table_name;
```

Step 2

**Find and Replace** data from this `filename.sql`

Replace `NULL` with nothing and also `table` with `table_name`

Step 3

Import all data back to table

```sql
sqlite3> .read filename.sql
```

After this close your terminal/cmd and again open sqlite database and check that table.